# "Что" является общим элементом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Некоторые сообщают, что из всего потомства у него остались лишь дочери(,) и что от одной из них у него был внук.

Нужна ли запятая в скобках или "что" является общим элементом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

*Некоторые сообщают, что из всего потомства у него остались лишь дочери и что от одной из них у него был внук.*

Данное предложение сложноподчиненное, в его состав входят два изъяснительных придаточных (с одинаковым союзом ***что***), для которых общим элементом является главное предложение ***Некоторые сообщают***.

> 3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится: *Отец мой говорил, **что он не видывал таких хлебов и что нынешний год урожай отличный*** (Акс.)

Источник: [**§ 35. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными**](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=139) (Розенталь).

Comment: С каждым ответом на свои вопросы узнаю больше, чем ожидал. Спасибо!